# how we can capture particular stored procedure's resource usage in mysql server

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

how we can capture particular stored procedure's resource usage in MYSQL server and also for query that how we can get resource usage for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some queries that you can use to help you monitor this, such as:

View Running Queries:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST ;
```

View the MySQL server status variables which will give you statistical performance data:

```
mysql> SHOW SERVER STATUS;
```

Also, you can show an engine's status:

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Navicat (Tools -> Server monitor) https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql
2. Jet Profiler for Mysql: https://www.jetprofiler.com/
3. New Relic: https://newrelic.com

All of them have trial versions.